# Buttons on top of each other not side by side?

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons, that I was hoping to have side by side, however their right on top of each that I can't figure out why.. here's what i'm looking at.

[image]

here's my code.

CSS:

```
  button {
  position: absolute;  
  top: 250px;
   left: -15px; 
   z-index: 9999;
  color:white;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 7px 35px;
  font: 300 150% langdon;
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  } 

  button:hover {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }

  button:active {
  background: #2e2e2e;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Need to see your HTML too, but I suspect the issues like with `position: absolute;`

Comment: Assign different ids to the buttons and use different styles for both with different absolute positions...

Comment: `position: absolute` removes elements from the normal flow of the document. That means the first one won't push the second one next to it.

Comment: my buttons are, <button class="button">SIGN UP</button>
<button class="button"> LOGIN </button>

Answer (score 2):

`position:absolute` removes the elements from the normal document flow. Thus, they will be positioned on top of each other where specified (`top: 250px;`, `left: -15px;`) since they share the same position styles.

For your scenario, it would probably be better to use floats and margins:

```
button {
    float:left;
    margin-top:250px;
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming the transparency is also positioned absolutely. Try removing the positioning on that (adding a `float` if necessary) as well. As noted in another comment, when not fully understood absolute positioning can create hard to update sites and is usually not the best course of action.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `position: absolute;` should be avoided; you're taking an element out of the standard flow (which means no more side by side or top to bottom reflowing).

If you insist on using it, you need two different positioning rules for your buttons so you can assign them to different places.

Comment: It should be avoided if not understood. Once you understand css positioning, it is a powerful tool.

Comment: Yes, and if you reach a point where you need it, then fine, but too often developers go immediately for absolute positioning which creates rickety, hard to update sites :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `position:static;` I read that it renders elements in order as they appear in the document flow.