# Buttons now under transparency?

Tags: html, css

I've been having trouble all day with these buttons. First, both buttons were on top of each other looking like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utw3r.jpg and now after posting here asking what to do, it looks like this now, https://i.stack.imgur.com/CozvI.jpg
I was told to change in my css from this :

CSS:
          button {
          float:left;
          margin-top:250px;
          color:white;
          display: block;
          margin: 30px;
          padding: 7px 35px;
           font: 300 150% langdon;
           background: transparent;
           border: 3px solid white;
           cursor: pointer;
           }

```
  button:hover {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }

  button:active {
  background: #2e2e2e;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  }
```

Comment: We need some code to work with mate...

Comment: I just added the css, that has to do with the buttons.

Comment: Nice design, but you need to provide a fiddle to get a good answer ...

Comment: So what are you looking to do?  They don't look like they are ontop of eachother anymore..

Comment: @user3430532 Where is the problem ??

Comment: the problem is, the buttons are under the transparency which makes them, unclickable.. I would like them under where it says, "Start Here"

Comment: here's the link to the other question I posted if this helps.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160665/buttons-on-top-of-each-other-not-side-by-side

Comment: @user3430532 create the page which your are working on, in this website http://jsfiddle.net/ , then give us the link so we can help you in the correct way

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/k2n49/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you just need to add `position:relative` to the `div` which contains the buttons, so make it like this:

### HTML

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    GO ROAM</br>
    START HERE.
    <button>SIGN UP</button>
    <button>LOG IN</button>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the working code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rkMUp/). I have removed the absolute path from the buttons and added `display: inline-block;` so now they're one next to the other. I have also added the `top: 250px` declaration in the wrapper.

```
button {
  color:white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px;
  padding: 7px 35px;
  font: 300 150% langdon;
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;

} 

button:hover {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button:active {
  background: #2e2e2e;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Show us the html! If you have a wrapper for the buttons, you could set it to `position: relative` and a high `z-index`, this could fix the issue.

Comment: <h1 style="font-family: langdon; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; font-size: 108px; color: rgb(255,255,255);"> GO ROAM</h1>
<h3 style="font-family: mohave; color: rgb(255,255,255); font-size: 25px;"> S &nbsp; T &nbsp; A &nbsp;  R &nbsp;  T &nbsp; &nbsp; H &nbsp; E &nbsp; R &nbsp; E.</h3>


    
</div>

<div class=darker></div>
<div class=darker></div>

    
    <button class="button">SIGN UP</button>
    <button class="button">LOG IN</button>

Comment: Also! it moved the buttons, but once again their put on top of each other, but their clickable again.

Comment: just have to figure out how to move them under start here and i'll be good!